# History.js doesn't work in content script

Tags: javascript, history.js

I tried using history.js in a content script on the google play store, but the function is not executed when state changes
I tried the adapter bind method
in the manifest:

```
"js": [
        "js/jquery/jquery.js",
        "js/jquery.knob.js",
        "js/jquery.history.js", 
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
```

and then in the content script

```
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
    alert();
});
```

WEll nothing happens

and also this solution doesn't work either

```
 (function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        // ... whatever else you want to do
        // maybe call onhashchange e.handler
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    }
})(window.history);


history.onpushstate=function(){alert()}
```

I think this might have something to do with the scope in which content scripts run

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that window object is different for the content script and the page, therefore this is causing a problem. I have till date not found a way of using history.js in a content script in chrome.
I used mutation observer i.e checking for DOM subtree changes to solve the problem